# Make button go along with dropdown's animation height change

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a question here. I want to do a simple dropdown animation where I have this button at the bottom of the div's original height. When I toggle a class, div's height changes, and I want the button to always stay at the bottom. How do I do that? Code is right here:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var div = document.getElementById("div");

 function dropDownAnimation(){
   div.classList.toggle("dropdown");
  }


btn.onclick = dropDownAnimation
```

```css
.div {
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: 500ms ease;
}

.div > button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 300px;
}

#btn {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quasi pariatur illo earum excepturi ipsam.
  <button>Make me stay at bottom!</button>
</div>

<button id="btn">Press me for dropdown</button>
```

No jQuery answers please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var div = document.getElementById("div");

 function dropDownAnimation(){
   div.classList.toggle("dropdown");
  }


btn.onclick = dropDownAnimation
```

```css
.div {
     position:relative;
     padding-bottom:50px;
     background-color: gray;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 18px;
     width: 150px;
     transition: 500ms ease;
}
 .div > button {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0%;
     bottom: 0%;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     font-size: 10px;
}
 .dropdown {
     height: 300px;
}
 #btn {
     margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quasi pariatur illo earum excepturi ipsam.
  <button>Make me stay at bottom!</button>
</div>

<button id="btn">Press me for dropdown</button>
```

Comment: Meanwhile yes, it's working, and you've basically answered my question, but not entirely. Can you find another way without absolute positioning? Thanks.

Comment: Yes there are other options but they are not good ones, above css I think suits well can you let me know what actually you want to achieve?

Comment: You could accomplish it using `flex`. Your method, @NishantDixit, is simpler, but a flex column would mostly avoid overlap.

Comment: I did not see the position relative on the parent! It's working perfectly. Thanks. It was messing up everything if I added absolute positioning to the button without relative positioning on the parent. Cheers!

Comment: Haha sorry I first verified your answer, saw awran5's answer, saw that it worked, unverified this one, verified his, came back and looked at your answer and saw position relative in there, unverified awran5's answer and verified yours again, lol. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nishant code snippet shows, You don't need JavaScript to do so, only add this to your main `div`

```
position: relative;
```

and this to your button

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var sty = document.getElementById("sty");
 function dropDownAnimation(){
   div.classList.toggle("dropdown");
    sty.classList.toggle('btn_margin');
  }


btn.onclick = dropDownAnimation
```

```css
.div {
     position:relative;
     background-color: gray;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 18px;
     width: 150px;
     transition: 500ms ease;
}
 .div > button {
     position:relative;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     font-size: 10px;
}
 .dropdown {
     height: 300px;
}

.btn_margin{
  margin-top:67%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quasi pariatur illo earum excepturi ipsam.
  <button id="sty">Make me stay at bottom!</button>
</div>

<button id="btn">Press me for dropdown</button>
```

I think It will help. thanks